# Path Variable Problem in TikzEdt on linux

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

There is already a (unanswered) [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463418/path-variable-problem-in-tikzedt) to this topic in windows, but I thought it is clearer if I open a new one.

When I start TikzEdt on Linux I get this error message:

> It might be that you do not have Latex installed, or the wrong
>   pdflatex path is provided in the settings. TikzEdt cannot work without
>   Latex. Please download a Latex distribution, e.g., MikTeX or TexLive.
>   If you did install it, please check that pdflatex is in the %PATH% or
>   that the path in the settings is set correctly.

In installed TexLive and 'which pdflatex' gives:

/usr/bin/pdflatex

I don't now what they mean with "that the path in the settings is set correctly"? I changed "pdflatex" to "/usr/bin/pdflatex" in the settings of TikzEdt first at the field General>Command pddlatex and then as well in Compiler>Precompilation arguments (even i thought this would be odd). But it still doesn't work. Where to I have to change this?

If %PATH% refers to $PATH then `/usr/bin` is in there...

Comment: Have you a working LaTeX installation like TeXLive? I'm a Windows 7 user, but in my MiKTeX installation pdflatex.exe is in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin. Check where is pdflatex.exe in your installation. You can compile a .tex file with your editor and then look for the .log file generate during the compilation. In the .log file there is written where is your installation of LaTeX. I use TikzEdt and it work very well even if it's a software of the 2013.

Comment: Again not a Linux user but that path seems exceptionally short it should probably include the year of a full texlive say /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux I would look at answers to wider range of similar questions such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457208/change-texstudios-path-on-linux and if on say Ubuntu add that in your search

Comment: Have you installed TikzEdt as Administrator?

Comment: @vipa Yes, I installed TeXLive and it is working fine.  On ubuntu it is just an executable and it is not nessecary to install TikzEdt. But I ran it as administrator as well. 

I maybe just switch to an other program. 
Stil thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you want learn to write Ti_k_Z code you should read at least the tutorials in the [PGF manual](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) or a [minimal introduction](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). TikzEdt don't use the full power of PGF/Ti_k_Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing older requests for help I see we left you hanging without an answer. Did you resolve your path issue?

Since TikzEdt seems to have stagnated some time ago and was reputedly problematic on Mac/Unix you might find a recently maintained alternative previewer more suited to your  needs.

Thus for Linux can I suggest you consider https://github.com/fhackenberger/ktikz which may be better supported.
[image]

More background info at http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/

And a fuller list of alternatives here [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex)

Comment: I ended up to use a TexStudio instead. Thanks